# How to POST queries to couchdb-lucene

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-lucene

I'm using couchdb-lucene and want to submit a query via POST rather than GET which [the docs](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene#search-methods) say is supported. However when I submit the request I get a `bad_request` response.

The command I'm using to submit the request:

```
curl -v -X POST -d 'q=form:P' http://gareth:pass@localhost:5984/_fti/local/medic/_design/medic/data_records
```

The output of the command which looks correct as far as I can tell:

```
> POST /_fti/local/medic/_design/medic/data_records?debug=true HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic Z2FyZXRoOnBhc3M=
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:5984
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 8
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 8 out of 8 bytes
```

The response:

```
{"reason":"bad_request","code":400}
```

If I do the equivalent GET request everything works as expected:

```
curl -v http://user:pass@localhost:5984/_fti/local/medic/_design/medic/data_records?q=form:P
{"limit":25,"etag":"235dad97d63","fetch_duration":0, ....
```

What am I missing in the POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a recent enough version? I just tried this locally on master and it worked fine;

```
curl 'localhost:5984/_fti/local/db1/_design/couchapp/idx' -d 'q=*:*'
{"q":"*:*","fetch_duration":....
```

Comment: sounds like you have earlier than 1.0, which is when POST was added. Upgrade to 1.0.1.

Comment: Yeah that was it. I should've checked that first. Thanks for your help!